# my bool function not working,dont know why

Tags: c++, primes

My intention was to count the sum of prime numbers in a certain range. Its working fine when the range is less than or equal to 8. When I take input 9 it shows output 26 while the answer is 17. My program identifying 9 as a prime and adding with the sum.

```
{
  for(int i=3; i*i<=n; i+=2)
  {
      if(n%i==0) return false;
  }

  return true;
}`

`int main(){

    int t,sum=0;
    cin >> t;
    for(int k = 0; k < t; k++){
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        if(n>=2) sum=2;`

       ` for(int i=3;i<=n;i+=2)
        {
            ifPrime(i);
            if(ifPrime) sum=sum+i;
        }`

      ` cout<<sum<<endl;
       sum=0;
    }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: whats 'ifPrime'

Comment: please post complete program

Comment: @EricPostpischil - my bad, there was no language tag and I saw c code so editing it in

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 2):

my guess

this

```
       ifPrime(i);
        if(ifPrime) sum=sum+i;
```

should be

```
       if(ifPrime(i)) sum=sum+i;
```

but without seeing all the code its impossible to say